How to update slice or array of struct in batches with gorm?
I see there's an option to create new records in batches using gorm function , CreateInBatches.
// Use the Batch method to update the records in the batch
    result := db.Model(&User{}).Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
        DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"name", "age"}),
    }).CreateInBatches(batch, batchSize)

Is there an option in gorm to update record in batches using gorm function, instead of looping through each record?

Batch updates are done differently depending on the database engine you are using. It would be probably difficult for Gorm to implement a solution that would work everywhere.
However it is still possible to do so using raw SQL. In the following example, we are using PostgreSQL.
The trick is to generate a VALUES list that will contain the updated values in your models and also include an ID so the values are assigned to the correct record.
You can name columns from a VALUES list, which will help assign each value to the correct column: VALUES (...),(...) AS tmp(id, name, age).
Then, use a WHERE clause to match the target table records with the ID in your VALUES list.
Make sure to use Gorm raw expressions so the inputs are still escaped properly.
import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
    //...
)

// Let's fetch some random users and modify them
var users []*model.User
tx := DB.Model(&User{}).Limit(5).Find(&users)
if tx.Error != nil {
    panic(tx.Error)
}

for _, u := range users {
    u.Name = u.Name + " updated"
}

// Create rows for VALUES list
values := make([]clause.Expr, 0, len(users))
for _, u := range users {
    values = append(values, gorm.Expr("(?::bigint, ?, ?::integer)", u.ID, u.Name, u.Age))
}

// Create the expression that will contain all the rows
// Because "values" is a slice, Gorm will join them with commas
// Prevent Gorm from adding parenthesis so it will generate the correct
// syntax: "VALUES (...),(...),(...)"
valuesExpr := gorm.Expr("?", values)
valuesExpr.WithoutParentheses = true

tx = DB.Exec(
    "UPDATE users SET name = tmp.name, age = tmp.age, updated_at = NOW() FROM (VALUES ?) tmp(id,name,age) WHERE users.id = tmp.id",
    valuesExpr,
)

Notes:

You may notice the ::bigint cast. It is there to make sure pgx (the Go pgsql driver used in this example) is using the correct type. Otherwise it may fail to detect the correct type and use "text" or something instead, which will result in an error.
Because you are using a raw query, Gorm won't know if it has to update special columns such as updated_at and other hooks. Be sure to include those manually.

